# Error on running android project on emulator - No command output when running

Tags: android, eclipse

Am developing small android project. For testing that APK in 2.3.6 device, I changed to **minSdkVersion="10"** form **minSdkVersion="12".** After that am running that project, application didn't load on **emulator.**  It displaying error on **Error Log** `No command output when running: 'am start -n org.example.androidsdk.demo/org.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER' on device emulator-5554.` After that i try to run simple hello world getting same error. What is problem on my Eclipse ?